# Cannot update ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, software-updater

I cannot update Ubuntu 12.10
tried update and upgrade 
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to correct the problem.

sorry cannot post image

Comment: Not enough information, copy and paste your terminal results here.

Comment: Did you run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: pls help cannot update

Answer (score 2):

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open the terminal

copy and paste this and press enter

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: did it found this                                                           dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0026' near line 0:
 newline in field name `#padding'